# How can I change keyboard layout in password field in Safari?

Tags: keyboard, macos, password

I've macbook pro with macOS Sierra 10.12.3 and Safari 10.0.3.

I just need to change input language (eg. to Russian) for password input field, but it's disabled.

I've 2 keyboard layouts/languages enabled system-wide: English and Russian and I can write with this layouts everywhere except password fields in browsers.

So, how can I enable non-english layouts for this fields?

Comment: Try other browsers like Firefox and Chrome.  Do you have the same problem there?

Comment: Sorry for really late reply, but no, it's only a Safari issue.